# How to hash the <input> type password?

Tags: javascript, html, hash, hashcode

I have a JavaScript function that is supposed to create a new login form and then submit the form. But for some reason the function is not submitting anything to the PHP file. Is the function correct or am I doing something wrong here?

**Javascript:**

```js
function passval() {
    var email = document.getElementById("loginEmail").value;
    var passv = document.getElementById("loginPass").value;
    alert (email + passv);
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    f.setAttribute('action',"../ru/login/ajax/loginchk.php");
    var p = document.createElement("input");
    var email = document.createElement("input");
    alert (p + email)
    // Add the new element to our form. 
    f.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "text";
    p.value = hex_sha512(passv.value);
    alert (p.value);
    f.appendChild(email);
    emai.name = "emailadd";
    emai.type = "text";
    emai.value = email;
    alert (emai.value);
    password.value = "";
    email = "";
    //submit the form.
    f.submit();
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<form id="login" method="post" action="">
    <a href="#" id="flipToRecover" class="flipLink">Forgot?</a>
    <input type="text" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" value="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="loginPass" id="loginPass" value="pass" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login" onclick="passval()"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't try to hash the password on the client. Hash it on the server before storing it.

Comment: ^^ What he said, sending just the hash from the client is the same as sending the password, all one has to do is intercept the hash, and send the same hash, and you're in, same as with the password, makes no difference.

Comment: Got it, thanks i'll do that.

Comment: @FalconC, thanks buddy for the editing, sorry for the mistakes I have made in there.

Comment: @Quentin  I've just had a review over the principals and your suggestions, unfortunately I am not able to figure out how to send the pass to PHP if I don't use the javascript to hash it, the pass has to be sent to the server some how, right? What should I do with the password if I don't hash it? isn't the createElement helpful to hide the password?

Comment: You just submit the form. If you want to protect it in transit then serve the form and the form's action over HTTPS instead of plain HTTP.

Comment: could you give me a reference to "serving the form and the form's action over HTTPS" ? appreciated